# jQuery .append() with wait for render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting some html from a webservice that I'm appending to a div. This is my success function:

```
function SucceededCallback(result) {
  // get the div element
  var RsltElem = $(".placeholder");

  // update div inner Html
  RsltElem.append(result);

  $('.loading-gif').hide();
}
```

Is there any way I can get `.append()` not to display until the browser is finished loading and painting it?

I'd rather not use `.append(result).slideDown(n)` as n could be anything, depending on what the webservice sends me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Is there any way I can get .append() not to display until the browser is finished loading and painting it?` this is what is happening already. `append()` is not an async method

Answer (score 0):

Consider using

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        ...
    });
```

like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        //get the div element
        var RsltElem = $(".placeholder");

        //update div inner Html
        RsltElem.append(result);


        $('.loading-gif').hide();
});
```

I don't know what you are painting and when it will complete, so you could also use this:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

Code inside the function only runs when the entire page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    //everything is loaded
});
```